# Removing certain parts of a cell

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

So i am making a dataframe with players for the top 5 leagues in Europe (soccer). i have a column in this data frame called "PlayerURL". in this columns i have the URL of every player for every season. they look like this. `"/en/players/c0617e2b/Dani-Ceballos"` or `"/en/players/6c203af0/Yves-Bissouma"`. i have 1003 cells looking like this with different names. i want to remove the "/en/players/" and their name at the end, so i just keep the "code" in the middle. is there someone who can help me with doing this?

i an new to this.. any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex pattern and `gsub` or `stringr::str_replace` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

data.frame(
  url = c(
    "/en/players/c0617e2b/Dani-Ceballos",
    "/en/players/6c203af0/Yves-Bissouma"
  )
) |>
  mutate(
    code = gsub("^/en/players/(.*)/.*$", "\\1", url)
  ) |> 
  mutate(
    code1 = stringr::str_replace(url, "^/en/players/(.*)/.*$", "\\1")
  )
#>                                  url     code    code1
#> 1 /en/players/c0617e2b/Dani-Ceballos c0617e2b c0617e2b
#> 2 /en/players/6c203af0/Yves-Bissouma 6c203af0 6c203af0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

players <- tribble(
  ~PlayerURL,
  "/en/players/c0617e2b/Dani-Ceballos",
   "/en/players/6c203af0/Yves-Bissouma"
)

players %>% 
  mutate(code = sapply(strsplit(PlayerURL, "/"), "[[", 4))


#   url                                code    
#   <chr>                              <chr>   
# 1 /en/players/c0617e2b/Dani-Ceballos c0617e2b
# 2 /en/players/6c203af0/Yves-Bissouma 6c203af0
```

Comment: Hi J K, welcome to SO. The OP wants to retain the codes, not the player names. How would you modify your code to return the codes? Thanks

Comment: thanks @LTyrone - solution amended accordingly